# Bibliography at beginning of document

Tags: bibliographies, front-matter

The usual practice is that the bibliography is in the last pages of a book. However, I found a book in which the bibliography is in the first pages, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

Are there some packages or classes for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing special about having LaTeX generate the bibliography early rather than late in the document. There is certainly no need for a special package or a specialized document class. If you use BibTeX or biblatex to generate the formatted bibliographic entries, all you need to do is to execute the bibliography-creating macro -- `\bibliography` and `\printbibliography`, respectively -- in the `\frontmatter` portion of the document. Depending on the document class you use, you may need to add a couple of instructions so that a line item for the bibliography is shown in the table of contents.

To give a concrete illustration, we may set up an example that uses the `book` document class, BibTeX, and the `plain` bibliography style. The resulting table of contents looks like this:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{aa:5678,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  year   = 5678,
  volume = 1,
  number = 2,
  pages  = "3-4",
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\setcounter{page}{5}  % just for this example
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface to Second Edition}
\chapter{Preface to First Edition}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} % create toc entry
\bibliography{mybib} % generate formatted bibliography, insert it here

\chapter{Notation}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Primes in Arithmetic Progression}
\cite{aa:5678}

\end{document}
```